# Access Violation exception when calling mingw dll from msvc

Tags: visual-c++, mingw

So I am having some trouble adding a  C++ dll compiled in Mingw to my msvc project. I have fixed the issue about linking that some people seem to have, but now when I call the function in the dll I have added I get an "Access violation reading location 0x00000014" error, which breaks on the operator new method in new.cpp (in visual studio 2010). I have read that there are differences apart to do with memory management, and I was wondering if that might be the source of my troubles.

The specfic dll I'm trying to build and run is cvBlobs, available here - https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/, which for some reason unknown to me is many times faster when compiled with mingw.

I'm pretty new to these things, but I was wondering if what might be happing is that the mingw dll is calling msvc new() method? Does that make sense? I have looked the help on the mingw site, but while that has been useful getting me up to this point, it doesn't seem help address this problem. Please let me know if theres is anything else you would like me to provide.

EDIT:
I have included the specific problematic code, from my Visual Studio compiled code, in the hope it might lend a bit of clarity.

```
    //Grey is a greyscale image, thresh is that image thresholded
    cvThreshold(grey,thresh,0,255,CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    IplImage* outputImg = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(thresh), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1);
    //Blobs is where the found blobs are outputted too
    cvb::CvBlobs blobs;
    unsigned int result;
    //This is the problematic method, it is in the mingw compiled dll,
    //other methods from this dll seem to work. I'm tempted to say that
    //the problem comes in the cvLabel method, where a varible "CvBlob blob" is
    //first initalized. This is due to the stack trace that I am including
    //under this edit
    result = cvb::cvLabel(thresh, outputImg, blobs);
```

Here is the stack trace I mentioned higher

```
cvBlobs.dll!6e313f95()  
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for cvBlobs.dll]   
cvBlobs.dll!6e30135b()  
msvcr100d.dll!operator new(unsigned int size)  Line 59C++
nuon.dll!std::_Allocate<std::_Tree_nod<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >::_Node>(unsigned int _Count, std::_Tree_nod<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >::_Node * __formal)  Line 36 + 0x15 bytes C++
nuon.dll!std::allocator<std::_Tree_nod<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >::_Node>::allocate(unsigned int _Count)  Line 187 + 0xb bytes C++
nuon.dll!std::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >::_Tree_val<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >(const std::less<unsigned int> & _Parg, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> > _Al)  Line 550 + 0xc bytes  C++
nuon.dll!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> >,0> >(const std::less<unsigned int> & _Parg, const std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> > & _Al)  Line 699  C++
nuon.dll!std::map<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> > >::map<unsigned int,cvb::CvBlob *,std::less<unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const ,cvb::CvBlob *> > >()  Line 107    C++
nuon.dll!nuon::MarkerDetector::detect(cv::Mat & input, std::vector<nuon::Marker,std::allocator<nuon::Marker> > & detectedMarkers, nuon::CameraParameters camParams, float markerSizeMeters, bool setYPerperdicular)  Line 201   C++
```

I hope this edit might help clarify this for someone

Comment: Does the `*.dll` you've built with MinGW export pure C API?